# Numpy Histogram | Use one dimension to match bin, and another for the actual frequency

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, histogram

I can see something like

```
print np.histogram([1, 2, 1], bins=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

would yield

```
(array([0, 2, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

But I would like to not count [1,2,1] , but rather, a corresponding value associated with it.

For instance, ideally I would want something like:

```
print np.histogram([(1,100), (2,150), (1,300)], bins=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

to yield

```
(array([0, 400, 150]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

but it yields the same as the original result.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)'s `weights`.

Starting with your original data

```
orig = [(1,100), (2,150), (1,300)]
```

Split it like this:

```
keys = [key for (key, _) in orig]
weights = [weight for (_, weight) in orig]
```

Then run

```
import numpy as np

np.histogram(keys, bins=bins, weights=weights)
```